# Problem with storing and retrieving very large numbers in parquet format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I have a weird problem when storing number with large number of digits (18 digits) as parquet and retrieved. I get different values back. Further drilling, looks like this problem happens only when the input list is a mix of None and the actual values. The case when the list is free from None values, values are fetched back as expected.

I don't think its related to display problem. Tried display with unix command like cat, vi editor etc, so it doesn't look like a display problem.

There are 2 sections in the code,

1. Creates parquet from list with combination of None and large numbers. This is where the problem is. For ex: value : 235313013750949476 is changed to 235313013750949472 as seen in the output.
2. Creates parquet from list with just large numbers and no None values. It works as expected.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

def get_row_list():
    row_list = []

    row_list.append(None)
    row_list.append(235313013750949476)
    row_list.append(None)
    row_list.append(135313013750949496)
    row_list.append(935313013750949406)
    row_list.append(835313013750949456)
    row_list.append(None)
    row_list.append(None)

    return row_list

def get_row_list_with_no_none():
    row_list = []

    row_list.append(235313013750949476)
    row_list.append(135313013750949496)
    row_list.append(935313013750949406)
    row_list.append(835313013750949456)

    return row_list

def create_parquet(row_list, col_list, parquet_filename):
    df = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=col_list)

    schema_field_list = [('tree_id', pa.int64())]
    pa_schema = pa.schema(schema_field_list)

    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, pa_schema)

    pq_writer = pq.ParquetWriter(parquet_filename,
                                 schema=pa_schema)

    pq_writer.write_table(table)
    pq_writer.close()

    print("Parquet file [%s] created" % parquet_filename)

def main():
    col_list = ['tree_id']

    # Row list without any none
    row_list = get_row_list_with_no_none()
    print (row_list)
    create_parquet(row_list, col_list, 'without_none.parquet')

    # Row list with none
    row_list = get_row_list()
    print (row_list)
    create_parquet(row_list, col_list, 'with_none.parquet')

# ==== Main code Execution =====
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**[Execution]**

```
python test-parquet.py

[235313013750949476, 135313013750949496, 935313013750949406, 835313013750949456]
Parquet file [without_none.parquet] created
[None, 235313013750949476, None, 135313013750949496, 935313013750949406, 835313013750949456, None, None]
Parquet file [with_none.parquet] created
```

**[Lib version]**

```
pyarrow                  5.0.0
pandas                   1.1.5

python -v
Python 3.6.6
```

**[Tested by consuming parquet as spark df]**

```
>>> dfwithoutnone = spark.read.parquet("s3://some-bucket/without_none.parquet/")
>>> dfwithoutnone.count()
4
>>> dfwithoutnone.printSchema()
root
 |-- tree_id: long (nullable = true)

>>> dfwithoutnone.show(10, False)
+------------------+                                                            
|tree_id           |
+------------------+
|235313013750949476|
|135313013750949496|
|935313013750949406|
|835313013750949456|
+------------------+
```

```
>>> df_with_none = spark.read.parquet("s3://some-bucket/with_none.parquet/")
>>> df_with_none.count()
8                                                                               
>>> df_with_none.printSchema()
root
 |-- tree_id: long (nullable = true)

>>> df_with_none.printSchema()
root
 |-- tree_id: long (nullable = true)

>>> df_with_none.show(10, False)
+------------------+
|tree_id           |
+------------------+
|null              |
|235313013750949472|
|null              |
|135313013750949504|
|935313013750949376|
|835313013750949504|
|null              |
|null              |
+------------------+
```

I did search in StackOverflow, could not find anything appropriate. Can you please provide some pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't related with Parquet, but with your initial conversion of the `row_list` to a pandas DataFrame:

```py
row_list = get_row_list()
col_list = ['tree_id']
df = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=col_list)

>>> df
        tree_id
0           NaN
1  2.353130e+17
2           NaN
3  1.353130e+17
4  9.353130e+17
5  8.353130e+17
6           NaN
7           NaN
```

Because there are missing values, pandas creates a float64 column. And it is this int -> float conversion that looses the precision for such large integers.
Later converting the float to an integer again (when creating the pyarrow Table with a schema that forces an integer column) will then result in a slightly different value, as can be seen doing this manually in python as well:

```py
>>> row_list[1]
235313013750949476
>>> df.loc[1, "tree_id"]
2.3531301375094947e+17
>>> int(df.loc[1, "tree_id"])
235313013750949472
```

One possible solution is to avoid the temporary DataFrame. This will depend on your exact (real) use case of course, but if you start from a python list as in the reproducible example above, you can also create a pyarrow.Table directly from this list of values (`pa.table({"tree_id": row_list}, schema=..)` and this will preserve the exact values in the Parquet file.

Comment: That fixed it, after removing the temp data frame. Thank you very much.